# Why is getText returns nothing for span class data

Tags: javascript, html, css, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

Want to get value of a span class named 'spacer-right big project-card-measure-secondary-info'

```
<span class="spacer-right big project-card-measure-secondary-info">1</span>
```

> code snippet:

```
  browser.waitForElementVisible('.spacer-right big project-card-measure-secondary-info', 1000)
         .getText('.spacer-right big project-card-measure-secondary-info', (result) => {
         console.log(result)
       })
```

Returns nothing at the console.

Comment: your query should be `.spacer-right.big.project-card-measure-secondary-info`

Comment: Timed out while waiting for element <.spacer-right.big.project-card-measure-secondary-info> to be visible for 1000 milliseconds. - expected "visible" but got: "not visible" (1045ms)
@Sysix

Comment: Your page may be loading slowly. Could you increment the timeout value of 1000 to 10000 just to see if it works or not?

Comment: @TheCoder what error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

This is Vishal here from the Nightwatch product team. Please try to use `.spacer-right.big.project-card-measure-secondary-info` as the selector and let us know if it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

there is 3 classes here `class="spacer-right big project-card-measure-secondary-info"`
spacer-right is a class
big is a class
and project-card-measure-secondary-info is a class
change it to `class="spacer-right-big-project-card-measure-secondary-info"`

Comment: Timed out while waiting for element <spacer-right-big-project-card-measure-secondary-info> to be present for 1000 milliseconds. - expected "visible" but got: "not found" (1026ms)

Comment: did you change the class name in the span as well ?